# SQL error using a CTE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I'm getting this error :

*Query Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';WITH convs AS ( select c.id, c.title, c.seen, c.id_receiver, c.id_send' at line 1*

when i use this query :

```
$query = ";WITH convs AS (
        select c.id, c.title, c.seen, c.id_receiver, c.id_sender
        from conversations c
        )
        select id, title, seen, id_receiver, id_sender
        from convs
        where id_receiver = '5'
        order by title desc limit 0,25";

$res = mysqli_query($connection ,$query);
```

Am i missing something ?
Your help would be much appreciated.

PS : i minimised the query to make it simple for this context, if you help me find the solution, i may have another problem with the full query. So i might come back to you for more help. Thank's in advance.

**EDIT (WHOLE QUERY)**

```
$query = "WITH convs AS (
        select c.id, c.title, c.seen, c.id_receiver, c.id_sender,
        (select max(date) from messages where id_conversation = c.id and id_user <> '$iduser') as last_msg,
        (select top 1 id_user from messages where id_conversation = c.id and id_user <> '$iduser' order by date desc) as last_user,
        (select count(distinct id_user) from messages where id_conversation = c.id) as nbruser,
        (select count(*) from messages where id_conversation = c.id) as nbrmsg,
        (select username from users where id = c.id_sender) as sender, (select username from users where id = c.id_receiver) as receiver,
        (select count(*) from deleted_conversations where id_user='$iduser' and id_conversation=c.id) as deleted,
        from conversations c
        )
        select id, title, seen, id_receiver, id_sender, receiver, sender, last_msg, last_user, deleted, nbruser, nbrmsg
        from convs
        where (id_receiver = '$iduser' or (id_sender == '$iduser' and nbruser > 1)) and deleted = 0
        order by last_msg desc limit $pageLimit,$REC_PER_PAGE";
```

What pushed me to use CTE is the need of using aliases in where clause. And as you can see i have many of them.

Can you give me an example of how to use views/temporary tables to achieve my purpose ?

Comment: I guess we are missing order by clause. You wrote desc directly.

Comment: @I_am_Batman in my actual code, it is present, but still not working. i surely just mistyped it in here (i edited the question).

Comment: Is this still a typo that you did not give a column name to order by, after order by?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support CTEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTEs are quite similar to Derived Tables:

```
select id, title, seen, id_receiver, id_sender, receiver, sender, last_msg, last_user, deleted, nbruser, nbrmsg
FROM
 (
        select c.id, c.title, c.seen, c.id_receiver, c.id_sender,
        (select max(date) from messages where id_conversation = c.id and id_user <> '$iduser') as last_msg,
        (select top 1 id_user from messages where id_conversation = c.id and id_user <> '$iduser' order by date desc) as last_user,
        (select count(distinct id_user) from messages where id_conversation = c.id) as nbruser,
        (select count(*) from messages where id_conversation = c.id) as nbrmsg,
        (select username from users where id = c.id_sender) as sender, (select username from users where id = c.id_receiver) as receiver,
        (select count(*) from deleted_conversations where id_user='$iduser' and id_conversation=c.id) as deleted,
        from conversations c
) as convs
where (id_receiver = '$iduser' or (id_sender == '$iduser' and nbruser > 1)) and deleted = 0
order by last_msg desc limit $pageLimit,$REC_PER_PAGE
```

Comment: I'm glad there is another way to do it in mysql. However, i have now this error :
`Query Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from conversations c ) as convs where deleted = 0 and (id_' at line 11`

Comment: now it works like a charm, thank's to your very useful answer. the problem was the comma after the alias deleted : `as deleted,`

Answer (score 5):

MySQL/MariaDB doesn't support CTEs.  Plus, it is entirely unnecessary in this case:

```
    select id, title, seen, id_receiver, id_sender
    from conversations c
    where id_receiver = '5'
    order by ?? desc
    limit 0, 25;
```

Note:  You need to specify the column for the `order by` as well.

For more complex examples, you can use subqueries, views, and/or temporary tables.

Comment: Didn't know that MySQL/MariaDB doesn't support CTEs.
And you're right, in this **minimised** case, it is useless. However, my actual query is more complex. look edit section in my question.